# Writing a plugin: inserting image

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin to for quotations.
A quotation will have an author and a text.

The shortcode will be like this:

[portrait-quotation author="George W. Bush" text="I think we agree, the past is over." link="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushism" portrait="..."]

I've managed to do everything but the portrait. Could you help me understand how to do that. I suppose, the image should be inserted into the media library. And then a ready made wordpress function should prepare img tag with srcset according to what sizes the current theme is able to operate on.

I thought that an image will have an ID or something. But I failed to find any accessible in the admin.

Could you help me with the problem? In other words:
1. How to organize uploading portraits?
2. How to prepare img tags?
3. Which ready made functions will be helpful?
4. General comment on how to cope with the task most elegantly.

Comment: when you go to the edit page of a media, you have `post=1234` in the URL and this is the image ID. then you can use `wp_get_attachment_url` to retrieve the URL from the image ID https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: Since it's a shortcode we're talking about, you'll have to ask the user to upload the image somewhere (eg. the Media Library, an external server, etc) and provide the URL to the image to the shortcode so it can render it (eg. `portrait="https://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"`). You could then a) take that image and resize it if needed using the [WP_Image_Editor class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor), or b) you could just ask the user to make sure the image uses specific dimensions or else it might not fit in the quotation.

Comment: @cabrerahector, what you suggest will not be compatible with any theme. When an image is uploaded, several images are made according to the theme options. Some themes may have 3, others may have 12 or something. If I'm not mistaken images multiplied and resized when being uploaded. Then we'll have to prepare img tag in accordance with the theme options: if 3 sizes, then 3. If 12, then 12. Your solution seems to ruin any optimization and formatting that the developers of the theme implied.

Comment: You can always use `wp_get_attachment_image` and pass the id of the image to the shortcode. This will generate the `srcset` and will allow optimization of the images presented.

Comment: That's why using a shortcode isn't a good solution (as in user-friendliness) to begin with, you can't use the Media Uploader with it.

Comment: ... but passing the ID of the attachment (as other have suggested) is a good workaround (that still requires the user to upload the image first, then grab the ID and pass it to the shortcode.)

Comment: More to @cabrerahector point, you could create a custom post type as part of your plugin - which includes the image as a featured image. Then you can just pass the post id to the shortcode which has everything you need.

Comment: ^ This is a good solution.